# I need controls of video tag html5 in img tag

Tags: java, html, image, controls, thymeleaf

I have a website that would need to replicate the controls that appear with the attribute "controls" in the tag "video" in HTML5. These same controls you would need in the img tag for the download and preview functions. Any library or similar that can add it easily?

I need controls like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"I have a website"_ so you know how to use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript? Create a `div` for the pop-up content, put the div on a higher layer (read about CSS option of _z-depth_), add text and pictures, disable the div (is not clickable) and also give it zero opacity. When the "controls" is clicked then make the div enabled and with 100% opacity... It's not clear **exactly which part of this task** are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to add a slideshow on your web page using the controls that you mentioned in your question. If that's the case, you can follow the code below :-

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like an appropriate answer honestly.